# adding silent audio to channels 3-8 in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mapping, silent

This has been discussed before, but my question is a bit different.
Lets say have a video file with 1+2 as stereo.
Now I want to add 3-8 with silent audio - most likely using the anullsrc.
I need to map that generator to only affect channel 3-8.
Anyone has a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a source filter. Just need pan.

```
ffmpeg -i input -af "pan=8C|c0=c0|c1=c1" -c:v copy out
```

The first two output channels have their maps set to the two input channels. Since the other 6 are omitted, they will be mute.